Webpack 4 - Cannot execute npm run watch command - Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
I'm no expert of Webpack with Laravel Mix. I'm working on an very old project with Webpack 4 and Laravel Mix. I know the best solution would be to upgrade all packages, but actually I want to get the current solution just running.
On my dev machine is now installed Node.js version 21. When I run the command npm run watch for development, I got the error

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

I already googled and found links that tells, I need to add a special configuration output.hashFunction = 'sha256' or output.hashFunction = 'sha512' to the Webpack config.
But how to add this?
I've got in the root of the project folder a webpack.mix.js file.
This actually looks like this:
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js([
        'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    ], 'public/js')
mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.jsx', 'public/js');

Then I tried to add the following:
mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        hashFunction: 'sha512',
    },
});

But the error is still the same

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)

How can I change the hashFunction? I don't know if this would fix my initial issue, but I need to test this.
I am using Laravel Mix with Node.js 21.

I found the answer. I needed to put the following code into my webpack.mix.js file:
const crypto = require("crypto");
const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash;
crypto.createHash = algorithm => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm == "md4" ? "sha256" : algorithm);
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js([
        'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    ], 'public/js')

mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.jsx', 'public/js');

